# Negation Matching in JavaScript Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I have yet another javascript regex question.

I need to match any line that does not start with three letters and a pipe.

For instance, in

```
some text that doesn't matter
Test1
RandomLine
C|
FName
```

Test1, RandomLine, C|, FName must all be matched.

However,

```
some text that doesn't matter
TST|
MST|
RAD|
```

must not be matched.

**Note:** The above mentioned test cases are one string altogether and not 3 different strings

I was trying to come up with the logic and this was what I arrived at:

```
/\n.{3}\|/g
```

However, I need a way to be able to negate the **.{3}\|** in my regex, since I need to find a newline that is not followed by 3 characters and a pipe.

I did go through the site and I read that I may have to use the negative lookaheads to achieve negations but I was unable to achieve any success with that.

Is there any way to be able to accomplish this in JavaScript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `negative lookahead` here:

```
^(?!((TST|MST|RAD)[|]|some text)).*$
```

Comment: Okay, this is strange. I tried something similar and it hadn't worked for me.
It seems to be alright now. I modified what you suggested to match the \n and the 3 characters and it works correctly. Thanks for the help

Comment: Relying on "some text" is *not* the way to go here. This would be 10 billion times simpler and more elegant programmatically than strictly using RegEx.

Comment: Thank you for the inputs tenub.
I modified the regex to /\n(?!.{3}\|).*/g and it achieved what I was looking for.
However, what would be your suggestion?